# Is there a way to save a function to be used in a formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(AND('Sheet1'!G8>0,'Sheet1'!G8-'Sheet1'!H7+'Sheet1'!H6>0),'Sheet1'!G8-'Sheet1'!H7+'Sheet1'!H6,IF('Sheet1'!G8-'Sheet1'!H7+'Sheet1'!H6<0,0,'Sheet1'!G8-'Sheet1'!H7+'Sheet1'!H6))
```

I wrote it on VBA like that:

```
For i = 6 To lRow Step 4
    wsO.Cells(i, 8).Formula = "=IF(AND('" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 2, 7).Address(False, False) & ">0,'" & wsS.Name & "'!" _
        & wsS.Cells(i + 2, 7).Address(False, False) & "-'" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 1, 8).Address(False, False) & "+'" _
        & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i, 8).Address(False, False) & ">0),'" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 2, 7).Address(False, False) _
        & "-'" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 1, 8).Address(False, False) & "+'" & wsS.Name & "'!" _
        & wsS.Cells(i, 8).Address(False, False) & ",IF('" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 2, 7).Address(False, False) & "-'" _
        & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 1, 8).Address(False, False) & "+'" & wsS.Name & "'!" _
        & wsS.Cells(i, 8).Address(False, False) & "<0,0,'" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 2, 7).Address(False, False) & "-'" _
        & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i + 1, 8).Address(False, False) & "+'" & wsS.Name & "'!" & wsS.Cells(i, 8).Address(False, False) & "))"
Next i
```

I am looping by every 4 other rows to add this formula that I get the numbers from another sheet within the same workbook.
If you realize, just in this formula, the `'Sheet1'!G8-'Sheet1'!H7+'Sheet1'!H6` repeats 3 times, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to write it. Maybe saving it as a variable? I don't know. I have 4 more huge formulas like that where the same `'Sheet1'!G8-'Sheet1'!H7+'Sheet1'!H6` is repeating.
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Public functions created inside of modules can be used in your excel formulas. That would be one option.

Comment: You can use the `External` argument of the `Address` property to specify that you want it to include the sheet name. So `wsS.Cells(i + 2, 7).Address(False,False,External:=True)` will output something like `'Sheet1'!G7` without you needing to prepend "'Sheet1'!" onto it.

Comment: Other than my above comment, the rest of it looks fine to me. Like you said, you could save the addresses into a few well-named variables, which would make the vba code for the formula more readable if it needs to be edited later. But that's mostly for the benefit of your future self and anyone else who looks at the code. It won't improve the output.

Comment: Maybe using `LET` https://www.excel-university.com/remove-duplication-in-formulas-with-let/ depending on your target Excel version